# Pictureboxes with transparent background

Tags: c#, image, transparency, picturebox

I have two pictureboxes: One in the background with an image in it (picturebox1) and another one,(pic1) were i want to paint something (this background should be transparent.-->  pic1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;)

It look like that:

[image]

Everything works great except the font. why does it have a black border?

My code looks like that:

```
private void InBitmapZeichnen()
{
    Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp12);
    g1.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    //g1.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;

    Font f = new Font("Verdana", 8f);
    Font f1 = new Font("Verdana", 8f);
    Font f2 = new Font("Verdana", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
    Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.YellowGreen);
    Brush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.YellowGreen);
    Pen PenRaster = new Pen(Color.Black, 0.1f);

    if (mnuRaster.Checked == true)
    {
        float j = Rohrdurchmesser / (float)(trk.Value + 2);
        //g1.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        for (int i = pic1.Width / (trk.Value + 2); i <= pic1.Width - pic1.Width / (trk.Value + 2); i += pic1.Width / (trk.Value + 2))
        {
            PointF PRaster1 = new PointF(i, 0);
            PointF PRaster2 = new PointF(i, pic1.Bottom);
            PointF PRaster3 = new PointF(0, i+4);
            PointF PRaster4 = new PointF(pic1.Right, i+4);
            g1.DrawString((j).ToString("0") + " mm", f, b, new PointF(i + 5, 5));
            g1.DrawString((j).ToString("0") + " mm", f, b, new PointF(5, i + 5));
            g1.DrawLine(PenRaster, PRaster1, PRaster2);
            g1.DrawLine(PenRaster, PRaster3, PRaster4);
            j += Rohrdurchmesser / (float)(trk.Value + 2);
        }                   
    }
}
```

When I select a color for backcolor it works fine:

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `GraphicsPath` if you want to draw text on trasparent background:

```
private void InBitmapZeichnen()
{
    Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp12);
    g1.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    g1.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    //g1.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;

    Font f = new Font("Verdana", 8f);
    Font f1 = new Font("Verdana", 8f);
    Font f2 = new Font("Verdana", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
    Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.YellowGreen);
    Brush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.YellowGreen);
    Pen PenRaster = new Pen(Color.Black, 0.1f);

    if (mnuRaster.Checked == true)
    {
        float j = Rohrdurchmesser / (float)(trk.Value + 2);
        //g1.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        for (int i = pic1.Width / (trk.Value + 2); i <= pic1.Width - pic1.Width / (trk.Value + 2); i += pic1.Width / (trk.Value + 2))
        {
            PointF PRaster1 = new PointF(i, 0);
            PointF PRaster2 = new PointF(i, pic1.Bottom);
            PointF PRaster3 = new PointF(0, i + 4);
            PointF PRaster4 = new PointF(pic1.Right, i + 4);

            using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                path.AddString((j).ToString("0") + " mm", f.FontFamily, (int)f.Style, f.Size, new Point(i + 5, 5), null);
                path.AddString((j).ToString("0") + " mm", f.FontFamily, (int)f.Style, f.Size, new Point(5, i + 5), null);
                g1.FillPath(b, path);
            }

            //g1.DrawString((j).ToString("0") + " mm", f, b, new PointF(i + 5, 5));
            //g1.DrawString((j).ToString("0") + " mm", f, b, new PointF(5, i + 5));
            g1.DrawLine(PenRaster, PRaster1, PRaster2);
            g1.DrawLine(PenRaster, PRaster3, PRaster4);
            j += Rohrdurchmesser / (float)(trk.Value + 2);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see instead of `DrawString` i used `FillPath`.

Answer (score 0):

I think need to clear Back Color before you start drawing on picture box.

```
          Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp12);
          // add clear
          g1.Clear(BackColor);
```

So try this statement in your code...!!!